# How to adjust background image like Unsplash does

Tags: html, css

Can someone point me to directions how to make web page background image adjustable like [unsplash](https://source.unsplash.com/) has ?

I tried various combinations of

```
background: url('bg.jpg')  no-repeat center center fixed;
```

but I guess it has to do something with media queries but I have no idea where to start looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS: `background-size: cover;`